# Clojure SSL specify local cert to use as a client side certificate

Tags: ssl, clojure

This comes from the python documentation for Python "Requests" http library

"You can also specify a local cert to use as client side certificate, as a single file (containing the private key and the certificate) or as a tuple of both file’s path":

```
>>> requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', cert=('/path/server.crt', '/path/key'))
<Response [200]>
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

What's a good way to do the same thing in Clojure ? I looked at clj-http and http-kit but did not see an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [async-http-client](https://github.com/neotyk/http.async.client)?

It has specific tests for cert handling [you can view here](https://github.com/neotyk/http.async.client/blob/development/test/http/async/client/test/cert.clj). The [API docs are here](http://neotyk.github.io/http.async.client/doc/), particularly relevant would be the namespace [http.async.client.cert](http://neotyk.github.io/http.async.client/doc/http.async.client.cert.html).

From that test, a typical example of loading keystore and certificate is:

```
(def ks-file "test-resources/keystore.jks")
(def cert-file "test-resources/certificate.crt")
(def password "secret")

(defn load-test-certificate [] (load-x509-cert cert-file))
(defn load-test-keystore [] (load-keystore (resource-stream ks-file) password))
```